# How to send text over rf radio?

Tags: radio

I just got my hands on a 433MHz RF Wireless Transmitter and Receiver Module and I was wondering if anyone knows how to send text data (not just yes or no) using them and a RPI. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction like with a tutorial or something along the lines of that. thanks you very much!

BTW: I am using a RPI B

Comment: So you want to send text from a RPi over the radio.  Where to?

Comment: to another raspberry pi

Comment: each character is 10 yes/no one after another ... that is how serial communication works

Answer (score 3):

Some wireless transmitters (e.g. LC-2000PA) support UART mode, in which case you can just wire them to TX/RX pins of the Pi's UART, open `/dev/serial` on both sides, and start communicating.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualWire (trademark) is an algorithm for sending short messages over a radio link (e.g. by 313MHz and 434MHz tranceivers).

One of the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) examples is an implementation of the VirtualWire algorithm for the Raspberry Pi.

[VirtualWire example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_vw).